# How I can show text over an image and convert this to PNG or JPG in runtime with unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, png, textures

I'm try to generate a text over a image like the game "dulp". I need to know how to convert this to PNG or JPG with the text that is generated according to the player score in runtime to save the picture.

I don't need take a screenshot, I need put a modifiable text over the texture to convert in PNG or JPG.

See the example image, Image generated of the game "dulp"
[image]

Comment: Could you show us what did you wrote so far...

Comment: Hey @Otkachenio the example image is of the game "dulp", this image is generated when you share your score. The number 12 is my score, but the thing is that number es generated over the image and after this is saved as PNG or JPG to share after. I'm looking for something like this.

https://twitter.com/hashtag/Dulp
You can see here the different images generated by users in runtime when they share his score.

Comment: As @Otkachenio, please try to mention what (code) you've tried so far, so we can help with suggestions. That said, my suggestion is using a separate camera for just those objects and saving that. Look up "unity save camera image". All the best!

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found a solution to my problem here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/drawtext-on-texture2d.220217/